# Notification for finishing SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any plugin or tool give notification when a SQL Server query finishes? Maybe through email/ popup window. Thanks!

Comment: 'You've mail.. er.. query results!"  Via SSMS, SQLCMD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SSMS > Options > Query Results > "Play the windows default beep when a query batch completes"

That's the closest I can think of.  Integration with the windows version of growl would be cool.

I used to plug my mp3 player's output into my computer so I could listen to music and get computer sounds as well.